# How is CPU usage computed?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

The Windows Task Manager shows CPU usage in percentage. What's the formula behind this? Is it this:

> % CPU usage for process A = (Sum of
>   all time slices given to A till now)/
>   Total time since the machine booted

Or is it something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what is uses, but I think you are a bit off on the CPU calculation.

I believe they are doing something like.

```
Process A CPU Usage = (Cycles for A over last X seconds)/(Total cycles for last X seconds)
```

I believe it is tied to the "update interval" set in task manager.

While doing a bit of research for you though I found [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364157(VS.85).aspx) article that shows a microsoft recommended way of calculating the CPU time of a set of instructions, this might point you a bit towards their calculation as well.

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not "since boot time" - it's far more time-sensitive than that.

It's "proportion of time during which a CPU was actively running a thread in that process since the last refresh". (Where the refresh rate is typically about a second.) In task manager I believe it's then divided by the number of CPUs, so the total ends up being 100% (i.e. on a dual core machine, a single-threaded CPU hog will show as 50%). Other similar programs sometimes don't do this, giving a total of 100% * cores.

Comment: Dang!  You got the same thing as me...but as normal you beat me to it. How are you always here?

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you both Jon and Mitchel

Comment: "How are you always here?" huge LOL

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.02.vistakernel.aspx) as the way CPU cycles are handled with regards to scheduling was changed as part of Vista. I presume that this also applies to Win7.

Answer (score -1):

See the source code of Task Manager